# How to fix Bluetooth taking around a minute to connect to devices?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth-audio, lg-g4

With the bluetooth on my phone I used to be able to listen to music on my headset, get into my car while the music is playing, have the bluetooth hand off its "media" processes to the car's bluetooth, then pass it back to my headset when the car shuts off and its bluetooth connection ends.

Lately, my phone has not been doing that successfully, and will only connect (sometimes) if I wait for long (1 minute), or if I open my bluetooth options and force it to connect.

I feel like it's something to do with how my phone is "searching" for bluetooth devices around it, but I have so far not had any luck with poking around in its discovery and connection settings. I have tried resetting network settings and did a factory reset too but to no avail.

Basically the way the process should be is:

1. Headset connected as Media and Call device
2. Another Media Only device (that has been previously paired) turns on in range
3. Bluetooth passes Media to new device (speaker, car stereo, etc.)
4. Media only device turns off
5. Bluetooth passes back to the Headset

If anyone else has had a similar issue and knows of a fix including those requiring root access, please let me know.

Phone Info:
Verizon LG G4 (VS986), unrooted, Android 6.0